# How to generate all numbers between two numbers in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-redshift

How can get all numbers between two given numbers in Hive?

```
start    end 
 1        5
```

Results Like

```
start  end     all
  1     4   (1,2,3,4,5)
```